# Phantom deep link not openable on a browser

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, phantom

When I try to open a deep link in the browser to be able to sign the transaction with this format: `https://phantom.app/ul/v1/signAndSendTransaction`, this is the error I get: `-32603 Failure to decrypt payload`

If I open the deep link inside my app it works, but when I copy it and want to open it in the browser it does not work.
What could a possible solution be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately they won't work when pasted into a browser.

Deeplinks have to be handled by the operating system, so a user must either click the link or an app must trigger it to be opened.

Phantom deeplinks are mainly intended for native mobile apps (iOS/Android) and we generally recommend that web apps use the injected provider within Phantom's in-app browser